# Get info on a mapview selected annotation

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit, android-mapview

I have annotations on a mapview and a callout with a button on each. What I need to do is grab properties from this callout, ie. the title, but logging this line:

```
NSLog(@"%@", mapView.selectedAnnotations);
```

returns `<AddressAnnotation: 0x1bdc60>` which obviously gives me no useful info...

My question is, how can I access the properties of a selected annotation callout?

Comment: Where is this code being implemented? Also, there is a pretty good video on MapKit by Bill Dudney available from the Pragmatic Programmers here: http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-bdmapkit/using-map-kit

Comment: It is being implemented in the method that gets called when the button in the callout is pressed. I just need to grab the selected annotations title and store it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how

```
 for (id annotation in mapView.annotations) {NSLog([annotation title]);}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did in the annotationviewClick function:

Hope this helps

```
-(IBAction) annotationViewClick:(id) sender{

    [self.view addSubview:LoadingView];
    Annotation *ann = [myMap.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:([myMap.selectedAnnotations count]-1)];


    NSLog(@"Selected:%@", [ann tag]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mapView.selectedAnnotations` returns an array of anotations. You should access its items to get info.

Comment: right, I am able to see that, but i need to access the information about an individual Annotation, like its title.

Comment: I'm using MapView / annotations / annotations views since quite a long time and came accross the fact (bug ?) that selectedAnnotations on a MKMapView instance returns an array of AnnotationView ?!!!! Didn't you experienced the same (strange) behavior ?

Comment: No, it seems it always returned annotations for me